# "Богатир" чи "багатир"?

Tags: різниця-між-словами, вибір-слова

Вчора зустріла таке слово, як "багатир". Це правильно? Чи краще писати "богатир"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Ці слова мають різне визначення та різне вживання.**

З СУМ

> **[БАГАТИР](http://sum.in.ua/s/baghatyr)** Те саме, що багач. *Он двір стоїть багатиря гладкого,
>   Неначе городок* (Леонід Глібов, Вибр., 1957, 173);
>
> **[БОГАТИР](http://sum.in.ua/s/boghatyr)** 1. Оспіваний у народній творчості герой, хоробрий воїн —
>   людина-велетень з надзвичайною силою і відвагою. *Нерідко образ Леніна
>   набирає поетичних рис легендарного богатиря і героя* (Вісник АН УРСР,
>   11, 1957, 52); 2. перен. Про дужу, кремезну, працьовиту, відважну
>   людину. *За столом чотири сини.. Всі змужнілі, на порі, Як один —
>   богатирі!* (Микола Шпак, Вибр., 1952, 75);

[Мова - ДНК нації](https://ukr-mova.in.ua/library/paronimu/bogatur-i-bagatur)

[image]